# Some updates require a password authentication

Tags: update-manager

Some updates require password in Software Updater, but which package requires? How can I see?

[image: Screenshot (I can't add directly because of my reputation)]

Comment: @edward-torvalds There is only simple list without information, like this: http://www.virtualizationhowto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/softwareupdate3.png

Comment: If your question is which password, then it is user password of an user  from admin group,  the one you would use with sudo for example.

Comment: Ok I'm editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from source https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ

> Why does update-manager no longer prompt for the user's password?
>
> As of Ubuntu 11.10, update-manager no longer prompts for the user's
>   password to apply updates. This was decided to improve usability and
>   to make it easier for users to apply security updates and therefore
>   increase system security. The rationale is as follows:
>
> - Like in previous releases, by default only people in the admin group    are allowed access to perform security updates.
> - Only updates for already installed software can be applied without a    password. Installing additional software still requires people to
>     enter their password.
> - The password prompt had become an irritant for some people such that    they would just press 'Cancel' instead of installing the
>     updates. The    password prompt decreased system security for those
>     users.
> - People that did dutifully apply updates became conditioned to enter    their privileged password perhaps daily. When the user is prompted
>     for the password, it should mean something and the frequency of
>     update-manager updates meant that some people no longer thought about 
>     why they were entering their password. For these users, the password
>     prompt had the potential to reduce security.
>
> For environments where this change is deemed not appropriate, this
>   functionality can be disabled by the administrator via PolicyKit or by
>   creating users that are not in the admin group (a recommended practice
>   to begin with).

This probably also answers our question, why it does prompt.

Comment: So, it appeared because of the additional software installations, Didn't it?

Comment: @OrhanGaziHafif yes, that or if it is a security update.

Comment: Or if user is not a member of the `admin` group.